# Markers in different position in real world with Vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, android-augmented-reality, location-based

I set World Center Mode of Vuforia AR Camera object in scene to DEVICE_TRACKING to apply handheld device rotation to AR Camera object, it works fine and when I look around by my android mobile phone the Vuforia AR camera move in the scene too.
I set my location markers (Point of Interests) in their location in unity scene where x = latitude and z = longitude and set AR Camera transform.position to Input.location.lastData on each frame so when user move in real world the AR Camera also moves in unity scene.
My problem is here : Each time I run the app my markers have different position in real world when they should be static in the same coordinates.

How can I fix this?

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S7, so I have gyro.

Answer (score 0):

You can use specific target as World Center Mode. I am not quite sure but i believe each time you run the application your origin is your device. That is why your markers do not have static positions. Because each time you run the app the distance from your phone to markers change.